# Is public transportation avaible at night in Lyon?

Tags: public-transport, france, night-transport, lyon

Is public transportation available in Lyon at night? If yes, until what time does night transport run?

Comment: Given your previous question and dates you should include them because they may change the answer you get.

Comment: @Karlson when i put the links, poeple told me that this website doesn't allow , so i tried to re phrase the question

Comment: I didn't tell you to put the links.  I am asking to put the dates.  Because Euro 2016 affects the way that cities handle traffic, public transportation and security.

Comment: @Karlson okay i put the dates, please help, i am waiting and i must book

Comment: no help guys ..?..

Comment: You should find detailed infos here : http://www.tcl.fr/en/Getting-Around/Getting-around (there are also spanish, italian and german versions).

Comment: @sarahsarah Sometimes it takes some time for the person with the right knowledge (or inclination to spend time researching) to come along an answer the question. (Especially when the inital formulation of the question wasn't good). You could try and find out for yourself, then post the answer here.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Lyon#By_public_transport)

> Metros and trams run approximately from 5AM to midnight. Some bus lines do not run after 9PM. Check the TCL website for details :
>
> [Detailed schedules](http://www.tcl.fr/en/Getting-Around/Getting-around) [French link replaced with English version, thanks to @audionuma]

There you will also find 4 night bus lines ("lignes pleine nuit" / "full moon lines") that run Thursday to Saturday night every hour.

Alternatively Lyon also has a functional rental bicycle system called "Vélo'v" (like "Velib" in Paris) that you could use for your trip home at night. For more info refer to [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Lyon#By_bicycle) once more.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to [check here](http://www.tcl.fr/Me-deplacer/Infos-trafic) for eventual strikes or other disturbances which may cause the metro to stop running earlier than usual.